# Integration of $\int_{\pi/3}^{- \pi /3} 16 \pi (1 - \cos x) dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate $\int_{\pi/3}^{- \pi /3} 16 \pi (1 - \cos x) dx$

To make this definite integral easier to solve, we can change it to $\int_0^{\pi/3} (1- \cos x) dx$

I don't know how to get to this integral expression. I know how to solve the integral but I do not know why both of them are the same

Comment: May you check if you typed this correctly? $\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{-\frac{\pi}{3}}16\pi\left(1-\cos x\right)dx \neq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\left(1-\cos x\right)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos$ has the property that $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$. This means that \begin{align*}
&\int_0^{\pi/3} 1-\cos(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/3} 1-\cos(-x) \, dx \\
&= -\int_0^{-\pi/3} 1-\cos(u) \, du \hspace{2em} \text{under }u=-x \\
&= \int_{-\pi/3}^0 1-\cos(x) \, dx
\end{align*}

This implies

$$\int_{\pi/3}^{-\pi/3} 1-\cos(x) \, dx = -2\int_0^{\pi/3} 1-\cos(x)\, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Before we have

$$\int{16 \pi \left(1 - \cos{\left(x \right)}\right) d x}=16π(x−∫\cos(x)dx)=16π(x−\sin(x))+k$$
with $k\in \Bbb R$. Hence,

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{- \frac{\pi}{3}}\left( 16 \pi \left(1 - \cos{\left(x \right)}\right) \right)dx$$$$=\left(16 \pi \left(x - \sin{\left(x \right)}\right)\right)|_{\left(x=- \frac{\pi}{3}\right)}-\left(16 \pi \left(x - \sin{\left(x \right)}\right)\right)|_{\left(x=\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}$$$$=- 16 \pi \left(- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) + 16 \pi \left(- \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)≈−18.213410795044$$